# GXT ScrollBar overlapping content

Tags: gwt, layout, scrollbar, gxt

I'm using `setScrollMode(ScrollMode.AUTOY)` to enable vertical scrolling when necessary on a VerticalLayoutContainer. However, the scrollbar overlaps the content of the container. The only way around this that I've seen is to call `setAdjustForScroll(true)`. The problem with this is that The panel will then *always* reserve space for a scrollbar even when one is not present.

Is there a way to tell GXT to only adjust for a scrollbar when one is present? Or perhaps use an event handler (eg ResizeHandler) and check if the scrollbar is currently visible?

Comment: just curious, what version?  2.x? 3.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to check in a handler if the scrollbar is visible, isn't it just easier to not have the content in the VerticalLayoutContainer?

For example I have:

```
VerticalLayoutContainer vp = new VerticalLayoutContainer();

vp.setScrollMode(ScrollMode.AUTO);

vp.add(layer1, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));
vp.add(layer2, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));
vp.add(layer3, new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1));
```

the layers(1-3) contain the actual content and are different types Ex. VBoxLayoutContainer, Container, VerticalLayoutContainer.

It works for me.  I don't think it is relevant but I am adding the vp to a CenterLayoutContainer that is added to the root panel.

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like exactly what I'm doing, which is resulting in the 'layer[1-3]' resizing correctly to the vp, but not taking into account the width of the scrollbar. This results in the last 10-15 pixels of layer[1-3] sitting underneath the scrollbar.

Comment: hmm. It appears you were right. However, a 'forceLayout()' call appears to be needed to kick it into action.